# MySQL: can i cron backup folder instead of using mysqldump so as not to expose credentials?

Tags: mysql, cron, backup

i'd like to run a cronjob to backup a database, but i'd rather not expose the credentials.  can i just backup the relevant folder like this

```
scp /var/lib/mysql/myDatabase remote@backupserver.io:/path/to/backup/myDatabase
```

instead of using

```
mysqldump myDatabase > myDatabase.sql -uUser -pPassword;  <--- makes me twitch
```

is there a better way to do this without exposing credentials in a script?  or am i worrying for nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: `mysqldump` creates a consistent snapshot if applied correctly (`--single-transaction`). Copying files grabs an inconsistent, possibly corrupted snapshot that could be full of problems.

For other options consider [`innobackupex`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html).

Remember, you can make a user with *read-only* access for backup purposes. You can also run the backup process locally and save an encrypted backup stream somewhere else. Then if someone somehow intercepts this stream and saves it they still have nothing.

Comment: ok.  thank you for explaining so clearly.  and, yeah, as i was making the post, i was like: just make an RO user... but i'm always looking for best practice, so i left it open.  thanks again.  :)